# How to reload a html page using python

Tags: python, html

I wan to reload a html page which I created locally in my computer using python. I have tried using this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('C://User/Desktop/total.html')
while True:
    time.sleep(20)
    driver.refresh()
driver.quit()
```

but it was throwing `FileNotFounError`. Any idea on how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Read this answer, might be helpful [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399355/refresh-a-local-web-page-using-python)

Comment: I used the same code but it wasn't working