# How can I repeat code every 5 seconds without clearing screen?

Tags: python

I am making a personal Live NHL stats program. Currently I have an output of

```
______________________________________________
Buffalo Sabres 0
Edmonton Oilers 0
______________________________________________
Toronto Maple Leafs 0
Calgary Flames 0
______________________________________________
Carolina Hurricanes 0
Philadelphia Flyers 0
______________________________________________
```

To get the home and away goals I am parsing NHLs JSON API like this.

```
   goals_home = jsonResponse["liveData"]['linescore']['teams']['home']['goals']
```

Right now when I run the program it just keeps repeating itself every 3 seconds without clearing the screen and looks messy. Is there a method to just clear the numbers and just repeat those in the same spot.

Comment: How are you displaying the output? Using `print()`?

Comment: print(str(home) + " " + str(goals_home))

Comment: Generate HTML snd refresh. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399355/refresh-a-local-web-page-using-python

Comment: You can try curses library for python. Probably needs some learnings though.

Comment: If you're just writing the scores to stdout with `print()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/37071230/245915

Comment: @balderman If you generate the HTML yourself, there's no need for Selenium, you can refresh it using JS. However generating HTML would require learning to use a web server (Flask or similar) and there are easier alternatives if OP is content with just terminal output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape characters to "go up a line", after which you will overwrite what's already printed. You just need to know how many lines you printed. Also be aware this might not work in every terminal.

```py
print("\033[F" * num_lines, end="")
```

If you want to do something more complicated, though, I recommend finding a dedicated library.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `print(goals_home)` to display the output, perhaps try `print(goals_home, end='\r')`. This `end` will replace the default new line, so that every time it prints, it will overwrite the previous line.

Comment: `\r` only goes to the beginning of the current line, so it works only for a single-line output.